# how to have full text search within a text without using RDBMS?

Tags: php, full-text-search

I want to search within a text with a certain criteria but without using any RDBMS and SQL.
here is my example :

text is :

> "Quantum optics has played an important role in the exploration of
>   foundational issues in quantum mechanics, and in using quantum effects
>   for information processing and communications purposes. Photonic
>   quantum systems now also provide a valuable test bed for quantum
>   simulations. This article surveys the first generation of such
>   experiments, and discusses the prospects for tackling outstanding
>   problems in physics, chemistry and biology."

criteria is :

> (optic* OR plastic OR organic OR "bulk heterojunction") AND
>   ("physics*" OR photovoltaic*)

my prefer language is PHP

How can I do that?

Comment: The performance will not scale, and impact your webapp as a whole...

Comment: Just use a tool for it, e.g. http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: point is not performance , I need to compare bunch of text against some criteria then add them to db.

Comment: Why do you want to compare it in PHP if you're going to add it to a DB anyway? But of course this is possible, as long as you write your own search feature. You'll have to parse the search query in a range of (nested) conditions and test for each. Maybe there are ready made solutions, (there are, they are called DBMS), but if there's none that suits you, I doubt you're going to get an answer here. Writing a parser like this, that allows using nested conditions will easily take a whole afternoon to write.

Comment: With a regex, 'physics' plus any character (.) would allow 'physics,' - is this intended?

Comment: @Dave: I think it's about matching *words*, so physicsfoo would be allowed, for example

Answer (score 1):

There is also [ht://dig](http://www.htdig.org/) an indexer written in c that can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are doing this in PHP, what you want is [Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html). It is compatible with PHP 5.2.x (and higher) and is fully unit-tested. It is obviously not as fast as Java Lucene, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) with [elastica](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica) in PHP.